# Play Store error "Your app or game that requires a game controller is not accessible with a standard Android game controller"

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv, gamepad

I'm working on a simple memory game and now that I published the mobile version I'm trying to create and publish a version of this game for the Android TV.

Now because this is a game I set the

```
android:isGame="true"
```

parameter in the manifest file.

Because of this parameter (I think) Google checks support for gamepad when you upload the game to Google Play Store. the problem is that I'm getting an error when I try to publish the game version for TV:

> Your app or game that requires a game controller is not accessible with a standard Android game controller

I'm getting this error message even after setting:

```
    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.gamepad"
    android:required="false" />
```

which specifies that this feature is not required.

The game can be downloaded here if it helps anyone to help me solve the problem: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ds.android.memorygame.mobile

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/games/index.html#gamepad)?

Comment: Have you actually added gamepad support? The error message is about your game not having gamepad support. The change in the manifest means that it can be played without a gamepad. Those two are not exclusive. A TV / Tablet game should have gamepad support AND be able to play without.